# Setting default background color for all pages on server

Tags: html, apache

I was wondering if there was a way to set a default server wide background color for all pages. Basically I have a bunch of images in a directory and when you click the link to the page it just opens up the image file in the browser with a default white background. I would like this to be black and possibly center it if possible. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Pete said, no.

But, you can do something like this:

Make redirection (using htaccess) for all the images in the directory so that `xyz.jpg` goes to `xyz.html` which would actually be a page with nothing but the background color defined and the image on top of it. However, you'd have to make a html for every image.

Although you didn't mention any server-side languages, let me explain you how you can do it in PHP, for example. Redirect all image files to a common page, say `styler.php` with the image name being set in the GET variable in the url. So, `xyz.jpg` would actually open `styler.php?image=xyz.jpg`. Then, from PHP you're read the GET variable, and load the proper image in the page itself while, of course, having the styled background just like in the HTML example above.

This way, it will appear that users are viewing the image link - it will say `site.com/xyz.jpg` in the browser, but the actual content rendered would be `site.com/styler.php?image=xyz.jpg`.

This is just the idea. To learn how to do it, read about Apache URL rewriting, PHP $_GET variables, etc.

---

EDIT

Just wanted to add that, if you *don't absolutely have to do it* via directly accessing image files, please don't. Visitors shouldn't have access to your directories, and you'd be much better off using a gallery of some sort. Just a friendly advice.

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't believe so. When you open an image in your browser, you're not actually viewing a page... you're viewing an image. The white background is the standard for the web browser.

You might want to look into using some type of photo gallery script. Here are a few that are most popular: http://www.design3edge.com/2010/08/26/best-free-and-open-source-php-image-galleries/

Comment: Note that recent versions of Firefox use a dark-grey background, rather than white.

Comment: @IMSoP And Opera allows custom default CSS for years now... But that's not the point.

Comment: @Shomz I just thought it was a useful piece of information that white isn't the standard for all web browsers, only the one the OP happens to be using.

Comment: @IMSoP I know, I know, I'm just saying that OP probably wants to change the look of his website to all the visitors, not just for himself.

Comment: @Shomz I know you know, and I know you knew, and I knew you would know, and ... I'm going to bed now!